# Python AutoPep8 formatting not working with max line length parameter

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, flake8, autopep8

I noticed one strange thing that autopep8 autoformatting in VSCode doesn't work when we set

```
    "python.formatting.autopep8Args": [
        "--line-length 119"
    ],
```

But if this setting is in a default mode that is line length 79 then it works well. Is there some issue with autopep8 to work only with line length 79 not more than that, or I am making any mistake in VSCode. Major feature that I need is when my python program line goes too long it should be able to break it in multiple lines. I don't want to go ahead with 79 characters' approach. My preferred approach is 119 characters. Currently, I have to indent big lines manually. Is there any other format apart from pep8 which supports 119 characters and indent lines with characters more than 119 characters automatically.

I am attaching my settings.json file data

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "python.dataScience.sendSelectionToInteractiveWindow": true,
    "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false,
    "editor.fontSize": 16,
    "python.formatting.provider": "autopep8",
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
    "python.autoComplete.addBrackets": true,
    "python.formatting.autopep8Args": [
        "--line-length 119"
    ],
    // "python.linting.flake8Args": [
    //     "--max-line-length=120"
    // ],
    "files.autoSaveDelay": 10000,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.python",
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
    "files.trimFinalNewlines": true,
    "editor.quickSuggestions": true,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": null,
}
```

Comment: is it that it's supposed to be `--max-line-length=119`?

Comment: Pep8 says --max-line-length=79 but Django says --max-line-length=119. Both are associated with Python. Even in GitHub code review it is 119. I just want something that supports python with 119 characters and formats my document automatically rather than me doing it, as it formats with autopep8 with max line length = 79

Answer (score 58, accepted):

experimental worked for me

```
"python.formatting.autopep8Args": ["--max-line-length", "120", "--experimental"]
```

[check out this link for proper format specifier settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_formatterspecific-settings)

Comment: `--experimental` was not necessary for me.

Comment: With autopep8 1.5.7 on Mac `--experimental` option was crucial to format according the max length, otherwise lines were kept above the provided max length.

Comment: @k_rus: do you know in what version was this corrected for Mac ?(i.e. not requiring "experimental")

Comment: @MrT77 Sorry, I don't know. It didn't work with version 1.5.7. I can see now that 1.6.0 is available through homebrew, but I haven't tested.

Comment: I'm using a setup.cfg in MacOs, so I define there experimental=True and max-line-length=120 but I still get warnings for line too long when it's greater than 100...Any idea on this ? (I'm using autopep8 1.6.0)

Answer (score 20):

This should work -

```
"python.formatting.provider": "autopep8",
"python.formatting.autopep8Args": [
    "--max-line-length",
    "120",
    "--experimental"
]
```

Answer (score 13):

As mentioned in the answer by @senti143,

On Windows, to set the **python** word wrap at 120 characters

Go to settings and search for autopep8

Find Python > Formatting: Autopep8 Args

Click on **Add Item** button and

add the value

```
--max-line-length
```

Click on **Add Item** button again and add the value

```
120
```

Click on **Add Item** button again and add the value

```
--experimental
```

As shown in the screenshot below

[image]

Now go back to the code and select the necessary code to format the line wrap at 120 characters

Comment: On VS Code 1.87 `--experimental` parameter is not required.

    

    `"autopep8.args": ["--max-line-length=120"]`

 is enough

Answer (score 3):

In the root level of VSCode settings JSON.

```
{
  .
  .
  "autopep8.args": ["--max-line-length", "180"]
  .
  .
}
```

But you should know that: these settings change from time to time. So see the autopep8 latest docs.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Comment: This new solution worked for me using recent VS code studio 1.84.2 (Oct 2023). It seems VS code studio deprecated setting `"python.formatting.autopep8Args"` and recently migrated linting tools, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/wiki/Migration-to-Python-Tools-Extensions#linting-and-formatting-settings-deprecation

Answer (score 2):

To modify the settings.json file for max line:

1. Install the autopep8 vscode extension
2. Open the vscode settings.json file (for macs, us CMD, P, then type and select settings.json)
3. Edit the `[python]` section of the file

The new format goes as this.

```
"[python]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.autopep8",
        "autopep8.args": [
            "--max-lin-length",
            "120",
            "--experimental"
        ]
  }
```

Comment: This is correct but the "autopep8.args" part needs to be outside the "[python]" object (should be on the same level of it)